# C# DataGridView Overflow Error

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, datagridview

I am trying to enter data into my DataGridView table from a database. The problem I am having is that I am only able to retrieve and set the first row of data from the database before getting an overflow error.
This is my code:

```
string passedvalue = "Tops"
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

string command = "SELECT ProductName,Price,Stock FROM Products WHERE Category = \"" + passedvalue + "\"";
da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command, con);

da.Fill(ds, "TempTable");
dt = ds.Tables["TempTable"];


int count = 0;

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    try
    {
        dgProducts.Rows[count].Cells[0].Value = row["ProductName"].ToString();
        dgProducts.Rows[count].Cells[1].Value = row["Price"].ToString();
        dgProducts.Rows[count].Cells[2].Value = row["Stock"].ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
    count++;
}
```

My database is as follows:

```
ID,ProductName,Price,Stock,Category
0, blue top, 5, 10, Tops
1, green top, 6, 55, Tops
2, blue trousers, 4, 4, Trousers
3, red top, 5, 5, Tops
```

When I run the code,

```
blue tops, 5, 10
```

is added into the table before the error is thrown.

I believe that I have included any required information, but if not, please comment it below and I'll add it.

***EDIT:***
dgProducts is a DataGridView

```
this.dgProducts = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
```

In the form designer

The exception is:

```
    System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233086
  Message=Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
  ParamName=index
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.SharedRow(Int32 rowIndex)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
       at program.productSelect.productSelect_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in \\--\--\Home\start2016\--\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\--\--\productSelect.cs:line 54
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Been a while since I've used this method, but try change this `dt = ds.Tables["TempTable"];` to `dt = ds.Tables[0];` and see if it works.

Comment: Please show the full exception and, preferable the stack trace too.

Comment: what is dgProducts and how it is initialized ?

Comment: @ChristopherLake Thank you for your reply. Your method appears to do the same as `dt = ds.Tables["TempTable"];`. `blue tops, 5, 10` is still output to the DataGridView.

Comment: @DavidG Thank you for your comment. I have added the requested information.

Comment: @jjj Thank you for your comment. I have added the requested information.

Comment: Do you have enough rows in your DataGrid? You seem to be accessing rows that don't exist - they won't get created automatically. Also, why not just do `dgProducts.DataSource = dt; dgProducts.DataBind();`?

Comment: I may be missing something... I am confused by the `foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)`? It appears you are looping through the rows in the `DataTable` `dt`. Then you place the string value of “ProductName”, “Price” and “Stock” into the `DataGridView` `dgProducts`??? You obviously already have the `DataTable` `dt`… Could you not simply set `dgProducts.DataSource = dt;`…?

Comment: DataSource fixed my issue. Will close this Q now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm new to using databases and the grid view, I was unaware of

```
dgProducts.DataSource = dt;
```

Note to self: More research.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Select DataGridView tool on windowsform, right click, select Properties, find the selection Mode in solution explorer. and set value to  FullRowSelect ... Problem must be solved..